# Shopify - Load 'collections/all' page on my front page

Tags: javascript, shopify

How to load `http://example.myshopify.com/collections/all` content
to my shopify frontpage `http://example.myshopify.com/`

I figured out a way that I hardcode `<script>window.location.href='collections/all'</script>` on index.liquid, but I'm pretty sure thats' not a clean way.

and I try to copy whole collection.liquid's code to index.liquid, but it prompt me `Liquid error: Array 'collection.all.products' is not paginateable.` error and no product showing the index.liquid page.

Any idea how to load `collections/all` on shopify's front page?

I'm using [Timber Framework](http://shopify.github.io/Timber/) as people recommend to start to build a theme

inside

Comment: You want to load them with javascript or you want to load them using liquid logic?

Comment: @drip liquid logic, i guess? anything will do, because this is bugging mi for quite a time, appreciate if you share any method. I tested liquid's include method, also a no good for me. : ( , thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Timber framework, you could change this line in index.liquid:

```
{% for product in collections.frontpage.products limit:4 %}
```

to:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
```

Depending on how many products you have, you probably still want to [limit](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/tags/iteration-tags#for) how many are displayed, or [paginate](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/paginate) the output.

E.g.

```
{% paginate collections.all.products by 12 %}
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
...
{% endfor %}
{{ paginate | default_pagination }}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You include this:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
    // here you have access to each product
{% endfor %}
```

This will loop all of your products.

You can review http://cheat.markdunkley.com/ what product variables you have access to in that loop.